# Get that StageName of the last Opportunity with an specific product at the Account Level

Tags: soql, custom-field

I want to display in a **field at the Account level** the name of the Stage of the last created Opportunity that has an specific product.

e.g.
An Account has 3 Opportunities. And I'm looking for the Stage of the Opportunity that has "Pencils" as Products and was recently created.

- Opportunity 1 is at Stage 4 , has pencils and was created Today. *(I
  want to get the Stage4 name for this one, as this was the latest
  created. and has pencils*)
- Opportunity 2 is at Stage 2 , has pencils and was created Yesterday.
- Opportunity 3 is at Stage 1, does not have pencils and was created
  Today.

I already have setup the logic for pulling the info from the Product to a field on the Opportunity, let's call it "Has Pencils".

This has to be done as a field and not just as a view, given that this field will sync with other systems outside of SF.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One low-code approach is using a combination of Roll-Up Summary and Process Builder.

You need a custom field on Account to hold the *Opportunity Stage*, a roll-up summary on Account to hold the *latest creation date* of its opportunities and a process builder on Opportunity to automatically update the stage at the Account.

1. Create a roll-up summary field on Account, eg. `Latest Opportunity Created Date`. Use `MAX(CreatedDate)` for the aggregation function and filter criteria `Has Pencils = true`.
2. Create a custom field on Account to hold the latest-opportunity-created's stage, eg `Latest Opportunity Stage`.
3. Create a process builder on Opportunity (on update event). The decision node formula should be `[Opportunity].Account.Latest_Opportunity_Created_Date__c = [Opportunity].CreatedDate` AND Has Pencils = true. And for the immediate action, use Update Record on the Account with only when the Account's `Latest Opportunity Stage` does not equals to Opportunity's `Stage` (to avoid unnecessary DML update).

Comment: This does work, Thank you!
What if I'm at the Max of Lookup fields I can use (25) I want to create a bunch of these fields, and looks like it will be almost impossible due to this restriction
I'm over simplifying this, but isn't there a way to create a field with some code that updates based on the logic you mentioned?

Comment: With apex code you only have to create a text field. With the above approach, you need to review your lookup fields and see whether you can reuse any of them (25 lookup fields sound like a lot of related objects!)

Comment: Yes, we have a lot. But we want to create one for each product we have, and we have around 12 fields.
Any pointers on where I can start doing the implementation with Apex?
Will it be using an Apex Trigger, and doing the update with the text field?

Comment: I would recommend trailhead if you are not familiar with apex trigger. Btw there is DLRS tool that *might* fit your use case here: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/07/a-declarative-rollup-summary-tool-for-force-com-lookup-relationships.html